Excel: Formulas not Recalculating
I am using formulas to calculate the sums of columns in a range of cells that are of a certain color. The formula is calling a simple VBA function:
Function SumColor(SumRange As Range, ColorCode As Range) As Single

    Dim ColorCodeValue As Integer
    Dim TotalSum As Single

    ColorCodeValue = ColorCode.Interior.ColorIndex
    Set rcell = SumRange
    
    For Each rcell In SumRange
        
        If rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorCodeValue Then
            TotalSum = TotalSum + rcell.Value
        End If
    Next rcell
    
    SumColor = TotalSum
End Function

The formula works but when I add additional items of the color in question into the range, the sum often does not update. F9 does nothing, auto recalc in options is enabled.
I have to double click the formula as if to edit it, and then hitting enter gives me the recalculated value.
I added to VBA:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

This does nothing, even when the sheet is closed and re-opened.
I have just noticed that if I set the cell color first and then enter the value, the sum cell updates the moment the value is added. If I change the color after the value addition, the sum does not update.
Any ideas?

Try Application.Volatile for the first line in the function.

@Blackcat, that won't work as a color change isn't considered a change to the sheet, though it will update when any other cell changes which is probably good enough..

It's not a good idea to tie calculations to cosmetic objects in Excel. You aren't seeing an updated value because changing a cell background color isn't triggering a recalc event (nor should it). As said in the comments, you could add Application.Volatile to the first line within your function, but you sill would not see an update value until you triggered a calc. To illustrate, click on any blank cell and just hit delete and you will see an updated value.
If you wanted to take it a step further (in the wrong direction), you could add the below code into the worksheet ( not the module). To do this, right-clicking on the worksheet tab and click view code then add the below code:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Me.Calculate

End Sub

This will trigger a recalculation any time you change cells (essentially the same as the example of deleting a blank cell described above). Again, there's almost certainly a better way to do what you want, but this should answer your specific question.

Application.Volatile did exactly what I need. I am just messing around with something personal, I can now color a cell and then when a value is entered the function recalculates all cells that call it. -@black cat and @pgSystemTester, thanks.

@carpboy glad it works. Clicking accept is the proper protocol for a correct answer.
